# TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy while upgrading spring boot starter parent from 2.1.8 to 2.2.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I am trying to upgrade my `spring-boot-starter-parent` from `2.1.8.RELEASE` to `2.2.1.RELEASE`, 
and, `spring-cloud-dependencies` from `Hoxton.M2` to `Hoxton.RC2`

But it's giving me following exception at runtime:

```
2019-11-22 15:37:02 [main] INFO  o.s.c.b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration -pymtId= - orderId= - Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='composite-configmap', propertySources=[ConfigMapPropertySource {name='configmap.merchant-service.null'}]}
2019-11-22 15:37:02 [main] INFO  o.s.c.b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration -pymtId= - orderId= - Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='composite-secrets', propertySources=[]}
2019-11-22 15:37:02 [main] INFO  c.w.p.m.MerchantserviceApplication -pymtId= - orderId= - The following profiles are active: dev
2019-11-22 15:37:03 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate -pymtId= - orderId= - Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-11-22 15:37:03 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate -pymtId= - orderId= - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 58ms. Found 4 repository interfaces.
2019-11-22 15:37:03 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication -pymtId= - orderId= - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration.taskScheduler
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:337)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.w.p.m.MerchantserviceApplication.main(MerchantserviceApplication.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:599)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:597)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getDeclaredAnnotations(Executable.java:588)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:630)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.getDeclaredAnnotations(AnnotationsScanner.java:461)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.isKnownEmpty(AnnotationsScanner.java:505)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.from(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:251)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotations.from(MergedAnnotations.java:322)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findAnnotations(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:764)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:531)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.BeanAnnotationHelper.isBeanAnnotated(BeanAnnotationHelper.java:41)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$ConfigurationClassBeanDefinition.isFactoryMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1605)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:491)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:223)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:167)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
2019-11-22 15:37:03 [main] WARN  o.s.boot.SpringApplication -pymtId= - orderId= - Unable to close ApplicationContext
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:599)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:597)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getDeclaredAnnotations(Executable.java:588)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:630)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.getDeclaredAnnotations(AnnotationsScanner.java:461)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.isKnownEmpty(AnnotationsScanner.java:505)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.from(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:251)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotations.from(MergedAnnotations.java:322)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findAnnotations(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:764)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:531)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.BeanAnnotationHelper.isBeanAnnotated(BeanAnnotationHelper.java:41)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$ConfigurationClassBeanDefinition.isFactoryMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1605)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:491)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:869)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:857)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:844)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:795)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.w.p.m.MerchantserviceApplication.main(MerchantserviceApplication.java:28)
```

My current POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.w</groupId>
    <artifactId>p</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>m</name>
    <description>m m</description>

    <properties>
        <ch.qos.logback.version>1.2.3</ch.qos.logback.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshosts</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Hoxton.M2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
                <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.logstash.logback/logstash-logback-encoder -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-oauth2 -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
            <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT 1: Debug Logs**

```
2019-11-22 18:23:49 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers -pymtId= - orderId= - FailureAnalyzer org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer@334ebcaa failed
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:90)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:777)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getSuperType(ResolvableType.java:467)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:456)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forClass(ResolvableType.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.AbstractFailureAnalyzer.getCauseType(AbstractFailureAnalyzer.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.AbstractFailureAnalyzer.analyze(AbstractFailureAnalyzer.java:33)
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.analyze(FailureAnalyzers.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.reportException(FailureAnalyzers.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure(SpringApplication.java:816)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:801)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.w.p.m.MerchantserviceApplication.main(MerchantserviceApplication.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
2019-11-22 18:23:49 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication -pymtId= - orderId= - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration.taskScheduler
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:337)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.w.p.m.MerchantserviceApplication.main(MerchantserviceApplication.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:599)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:597)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getDeclaredAnnotations(Executable.java:588)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:630)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.getDeclaredAnnotations(AnnotationsScanner.java:461)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.isKnownEmpty(AnnotationsScanner.java:505)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.from(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:251)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotations.from(MergedAnnotations.java:322)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findAnnotations(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:764)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:531)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.BeanAnnotationHelper.isBeanAnnotated(BeanAnnotationHelper.java:41)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$ConfigurationClassBeanDefinition.isFactoryMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1605)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:491)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:223)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:167)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
2019-11-22 18:23:49 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext -pymtId= - orderId= - Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@1c55f277, started on Fri Nov 22 18:23:48 IST 2019, parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@41488b16
2019-11-22 18:23:49 [main] WARN  o.s.boot.SpringApplication -pymtId= - orderId= - Unable to close ApplicationContext
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:599)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:597)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getDeclaredAnnotations(Executable.java:588)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:630)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.getDeclaredAnnotations(AnnotationsScanner.java:461)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.isKnownEmpty(AnnotationsScanner.java:505)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.from(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:251)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotations.from(MergedAnnotations.java:322)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findAnnotations(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:764)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:531)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.BeanAnnotationHelper.isBeanAnnotated(BeanAnnotationHelper.java:41)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$ConfigurationClassBeanDefinition.isFactoryMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1605)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:491)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:869)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:857)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:844)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:795)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.w.p.m.MerchantserviceApplication.main(MerchantserviceApplication.java:28)
```

Comment: Hoxton is not compatible with boot 2.1.x

Comment: The above error is coming with Hoxton.RC2 and boot parent as 2.2.1.RELEASE. Moreover, Hoxton.M2 is working fine with 2.1.8.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It's due to the OAuth library. Spring Oauth has been moved to spring security and there are major breaking changes.

We were using an embedded auth server with custom token store for mongoDB.